# Unblessed reference in Perl

Tags: perl, methods, reference

I have a Perl application that use mode `WWW::Scripter`. It parse very huge codes and all works great, just one problem occurs that I cannot understand.

I am getting error

**Can't call method "addEventListener" on unblessed reference 
      at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/JE.pm line ...**

It looks like an error in `JE.pm` (JavaScript Engine), which seems to be stable. This JE is called from `WWW::Scripter`, which seems to be also stable module.

Tracking JavaScript source I realized, that such error sometimes (not always) happens on the following part of JavaScript:

```
var addEvent=(function(){if(document.addEventListener){...
```

which seems to be correct as well.

Let's take a look at a section of `JE.pm`, where the error occurs >>

```
        my ($method, $type) = _split_meth $m;

        $proto->new_method(
          $name => defined $type
            ? $unwrap
              ? sub {
                $self->_cast(
                  scalar shift->value->$method(
                    $self->_unwrap(@_)),
                  $type
                );
              }
              : sub {
                $self->_cast(
                  scalar shift->value->$method(@_),
                  $type
                );
              }
            : $unwrap
              ? sub { shift->value->$m(
                $self->_unwrap(@_)) }
              : sub { shift->value->$m(@_) },
        );
```

and the "line", where such error occurs is its bottom part, so >>

```
            : $unwrap
              ? sub { shift->value->$m(
                $self->_unwrap(@_)) }
              : sub { shift->value->$m(@_) },
```

So what is wrong? What exactly error **unblessed reference** in this case means?

Comment: Some help: `perl -Mdiagnostics -e '$foo={}; $foo->method'`

Comment: [The JE module is currently alpha](https://metacpan.org/module/JE). Try producing a minimal test case provoking the error. Tiny doc, tiny script. Cut away stuff from the input doc that provokes the error to narrow it down.

Comment: You can also run into it when [calling a subroutine](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj#Indirect-Object-Syntax). `a $v;` can be interpreted as `a($v);` or `$v->a();`. In my case it probably was because I was calling a subroutine recursively without parentheses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An unblessed reference is one where one variable is not a legal reference to an object, but yet you're trying to call a function on it as if it was a legal object.

```
# perl -e '$x = {}; $x->blue();'
Can't call method "blue" on unblessed reference at -e line 1.
```

It's likely that `$m` in your above text is the function name `addEventListener` but `shift->value` isn't returning a proper object that has been "blessed".  It's a way of stating what `package` functions should be called inside of.  Here's some example code:

```
package Foo;

sub afunction {
    print "hello world\n";
}

package main;

my $obj = {};
bless $obj, "Foo";    # $obj is now a "Foo"
my $m = "afunction";

$obj->$m();


my $obj = {};
my $m = "afunction";

# this will crash, because we didn't bless it this time
print "about to crash\n";
$obj->$m();
print "we won't get here\n";
```

And running the above will produce:

```
hello world
about to crash
Can't call method "afunction" on unblessed reference at test.pl line 21.
```

Now, why your code above is resulting in an unblessed object you'd have to do lot more debugging to discover.