# How to Bless Objects in a List Passed to a Subroutine?

Tags: perl, object, scope, subroutine, bless

In my Perl (v5.30.0) script, I have the world's simplest object:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

package Thingee;
# Constructor with name new
sub new
{
        my $type = shift;
        my %params = @_;
        my $self = {};
        $self->{'somedata'} = $params{'somedata'};
        bless $self, $type;
}
sub printMe
{
        my ($self) = @_;
        printf "Data: \"%s\"\n", $self->{'somedata'};     # LINE 19
}
```

What could be simpler?  Now, in the "main" body of my script, I create a list of `Thingee` objects.  What I'm discovering is that the newly-created `Thingee`s seem to be blessed upon creation... but if I pass the list to a subroutine, the same objects are seen as unblessed.  Here's the code:

```
package main;

sub foo
{
        print "foo() ==========================================\n";
        my @ObjectArr = @_;
        print Dumper(@ObjectArr);
        foreach my $obj (@ObjectArr)
        {
                $obj->printMe();            # LINE 33
        }
}

# I make a list of objects:
my @ObjectArr = ();
push @ObjectArr, Thingee->new( 'somedata' => "My dog has fleas" );
push @ObjectArr, Thingee->new( 'somedata' => "My cat is fine" );

foreach my $obj (@ObjectArr)
{
        $obj->printMe();
}

foo(\@ObjectArr);
```

Output is:

```
Data: "My dog has fleas"
Data: "My cat is fine"
foo() ==========================================
$VAR1 = [
          bless( {
                   'somedata' => 'My dog has fleas'
                 }, 'Thingee' ),
          bless( {
                   'somedata' => 'My cat is fine'
                 }, 'Thingee' )
        ];
Can't call method "printMe" on unblessed reference at ./PassHash6.perl line 33.
```

Frustrating.  In the "main" part of the code, I can iterate through the `foreach` loop, and the newly-created `Thingee` objects are accessible.  But within the scope of subroutine `foo()`, the exact same `foreach` loop throws the `Can't call method "printMe" on unblessed reference` error.  Harmuph!

My favorite explanation for why blessing is necessary [comes from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710372/unblessed-reference-in-perl):

> An unblessed reference is one where one variable is not a legal
> reference to an object[.]

Okay, that makes sense.  But then how can all of the following be true:

1. My `Thingee`s are blessed within the scope of the "main" code
2. My `Thingee`s are ***not*** blessed within the scope of `foo()`
3. Within `foo()`, my `Thingee`s are nonetheless visible in the eyes of `Data:Dumper()`

Just for giggles, I modified the `foreach()` block within `foo()` to this:

```
foreach my $obj (@ObjectArr)
{
    bless $obj, "Thingee";     # New command here
    $obj->printMe();           # LINE 34
}
```

But now the script throws this error:

```
<EVERYTHING FROM BEFORE...>
Not a HASH reference at ./PassHash6.perl line 19.
```

Ugh.  Line 19 is from the `package Thingee` section:

```
sub printMe
{
        my ($self) = @_;
        printf "Data: \"%s\"\n", $self->{'somedata'};     # LINE 19
}
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Tip: `print( Dumper( @a ) );` is confusing. Use `print( Dumper( \@a ) );` (Same for hashes.)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks Ikegami, you save me once again.  You're like a Perl guardian angel.  Thanks for the tip!  In a tricky language like Perl, I need all the syntax tips I can get.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a reference to an array to `foo`

```perl
foo(\@ObjectArr);
```

Inside of `foo`, you do

```perl
my @ObjectArr = @_;
```

`@ObjectArr` contains a exactly one element, the referenced passed to `foo`. This is not what you intended.

---

**Option 1: `foo` accepts a reference to an array.**

```perl
sub foo {
   my $objs = shift;
   $_->printMe() for @$objs;
}

foo( \@objs );
```

---

**Option 2: `foo` accepts objects.**

```perl
sub foo {
   $_->printMe() for @_;
}

foo( @objs );
```

Comment: Excellent thank you!  I didn't realize that passing the list as a ref to "main"'s array was passing one indivisible object.  THAT makes a lot of sense.  I'll modify `foo()` to understand the ref to an array, thank you!

Comment: @Pete, You keep calling arrays lists. Don't do that. List is used refer to many things, and adding arrays to that list makes things worse.

Comment: You're not passing "a list as a reference". You are (creating and) passing a reference (to an array). Since you pass a reference, you receive a reference.